# How can I change the value of a range input from an integer to a string?

Tags: jquery, input, integer, range

I have a form with a range input-
    `<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="120" step="40" val="40">`

Instead of representing integers I want to send the value as a string.
eg- 0 = "freezing", 40 = "cool", 80 = "warm", 120 = "hot"

This will make more sense to the recipient. How can I swap an integer for a word before the value is passed?

I thought a jQuery if statement might work-

```
$("#slider").change(function(){ 
  if('this').val(0) {
    $('#slider').val("freezing")
  }
  else if('this').val(40) {
    $('#slider').val("cool")
  }
  else if('this').val(80) {
    $('#slider').val("warm")
  }
  else if('this').val(120) {
    $('#slider').val("hot")
  }  
console.log($('#slider').val())
});
```

I know my code is wrong, so any help cleaning up the logic/syntax is much appreciated, assuming it is possible?

Comment: `$('#slider').val() + ''` is a neat little hack to change any type (pretty much) to a string by concatenating it with a string.

Comment: I think its like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k1g88s5m/1/) ?

Comment: Thanks. To confim- 
I should change
$('#slider').val("cool")    to    $('#slider').val() + 'cool' ? 
Though wouldn't the value technically now be '40cool' for example? In my form the integers are going to be meaningless so I want to avoid the user or recipient seeing them at all.

Comment: @webmasterWannabee try my link

Comment: Thanks @KiRa the principal is similar except I would need to figure out how to apply it to a range input and store the new value instead of an alert.
That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: @webmasterWannabee What you mean is from range of `0-39` the value of `Slider is Freeze?` correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing based on the information you've given, but you'll probably want to have a separate field that displays your calculated value. Then your code above should work if you change it to update the text  (or hidden) field. I think slider values have to be numeric or else the slider wouldn't know if you were going higher or lower in value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in being able to pass the new value through to the form lies in using a hidden field with the same name as the input.
The integer value gets passed into the hidden field where the value can then be changed into a string with jQuery.

I set the initial value of the hidden input to the default start value of the thumb.
In this way if the user decides that the default entry is correct and they do not change it, it will still send the value through to the form.

I also added a console.log() so I could check the value was being passed through correctly and not just shown in the label.

html

```
<input id="bar" name="temperature" type="range" min="0" max="120" step="80" val="40"/>

<input id="slider" type="hidden" name="temperature" value="Warm" />

<label id="labelTemp">Warm</label>
```

jQuery

```
$("#bar").change(function() {

var value = $(this).val();

if (value == 0) {
   $("#slider").val("Freezing");
} 
   else if (value == 40) {
   $("#slider").val("Cool");
} 
   else if (value == 80) {
   $("#slider").val("Warm");
} 
  else if (value == 120) {
  $("#slider").val("Hot");
}

$("#labelTemp").text($("#slider").val());

console.log($("#slider").val());

});
```

view in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/webmasterWannabee/gyv4rgws/#&togetherjs=dOh4uHa3MS

Answer (score 0):

I think the input range value will only work with a number and not the strings you want, but you can display your temperature values in a label next to your range slider. This way the user will slide the slider and see one of your temperature values as they change the slider.

You can do this like:

HTML:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" step="40" val="40" min="0" max="120"></input>

<label id="labelTemp"></label>
```

Then your JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$("#slider").change(function(){
    var s = "";
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value == 0){
        s = "Freezing";
    }
    else if(value == 40){
        s = "Cool";
    }
    else if(value == 80){
        s = "Warm";
    }
    else if(value == 120){
        s = "Hot";
    }

    $("#labelTemp").text(s);
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate how it would work:
https://jsfiddle.net/vsf42kej/1/

Comment: Thanks so much @JustSomeDude 
Your solution gave me the correct starting point I needed.
After being told to use a hidden input as well I was able to modify it and create exactly what I needed as shown in my answer below.

Comment: @webmasterWannabee your answer is the same as mine, except you added an extra step for putting a value into a hidden field... the slider element is an input element, its value will be serialized with the form, you don't need the extra hidden field. When someone post something that helps you out refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: That's right, @JustSomeDude the hidden field was added because for me it was not working until I did. I am creating this form inside a unique CMS (not regular hand coding in HTML) so perhaps that changed things. The answer I posted was the one that worked for me and so I wanted to share it in case someone else was in the same position. I also apologise for not reading up on the litany of stackoverflow regulations and having the gall to thank you. Duly noted.